# Multiple CERT_HAS_EXPIRED errors when pushing a MeteorJS app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor

###### Type of problem

Failure to build

###### Summary

For a legacy Meteor project, we used to be doing git push to a bit bucket repository, and an automated workflow using CodeShip to kind of push the build to a heroku app.

Recently, we decided to move away from the BitBucket + Codeship workflow, to directly push from our local repository to the Heroku app. We therefore change the "remote" path of the repository from bitbucket to Heroku. But when we push, we face multiple "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED" errors that we have never seen before. Any experts here to share some some tips what could be wrong?

###### Contents of `.meteor/release`

```
METEOR@1.10.2
```

###### Buildpack version

```
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse
```

###### Logs

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (178/178), done.
remote: Updated 470 paths from 7b9dba8
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: +++ dirname -- /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/bin/compile
remote: ++ cd -P -- /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/bin
remote: ++ cd ..
remote: ++ pwd -P
remote: + BUILDPACK_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec
remote: + APP_CHECKOUT_DIR=/tmp/build_24f89da5
remote: + CACHE_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache
remote: + '[' -n 1 ']'
remote: + echo '-----> Clearing cache dir.'
remote: -----> Clearing cache dir.
remote: + rm -rf '/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/*'
remote: + APP_SOURCE_DIR=/tmp/build_24f89da5
remote: + '[' -n '' ']'
remote: + '[' '!' -d /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor ']'
remote: + '[' '!' -d /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor ']'
remote: + METEOR_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: + COMPILE_DIR_SUFFIX=.meteor/heroku_build
remote: + COMPILE_DIR=/tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build
remote: + '[' -z 1 ']'
remote: + mkdir -p /tmp/build_24f89da5 /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: + mkdir -p /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/bin /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/lib
remote: + '[' -z https://staging.[redacted].com ']'
remote: + '[' -z https://staging.[redacted].com ']'
remote: + '[' -e /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/meteor ']'
remote: + echo '-----> Installing meteor'
remote: -----> Installing meteor
remote: + HOME=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: + /bin/sh
remote: + curl -sS https://install.meteor.com/
remote: Downloading Meteor distribution
remote: 
remote: Meteor 2.11.0 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
remote: 
remote: Now you need to do one of the following:
remote: 
remote:   (1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
remote:   (2) Run this command as root:
remote:         cp "/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/2.11.0/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
remote: 
remote: Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
remote: docs.meteor.com.
remote: + cd /tmp/build_24f89da5
remote: ++ METEOR --version
remote: ++ ARGS=--version
remote: ++ HOME=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: ++ /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/meteor --version
remote: + echo '-----> Target Meteor version: Meteor 1.2.1'
remote: -----> Target Meteor version: Meteor 1.2.1
remote: + echo '-----> Checking if this meteor version supports --server-only'
remote: -----> Checking if this meteor version supports --server-only
remote: + set +e
remote: ++ METEOR help build
remote: ++ grep -e --server-only
remote: ++ ARGS='help build'
remote: ++ HOME=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: ++ /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/meteor help build
remote: + HAS_SERVER_ONLY=
remote: + set -e
remote: + '[' -n '' ']'
remote: + SERVER_ONLY_FLAG=
remote: + '[' -z '' ']'
remote: + echo '-----> Attempting to remove android platform.'
remote: -----> Attempting to remove android platform.
remote: + METEOR remove-platform android
remote: + ARGS='remove-platform android'
remote: + HOME=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: + /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/meteor remove-platform android
remote: 
remote: 
remote: While removing platforms:
remote: error: android: platform is not in this project
remote: 
remote: + true
remote: + echo '-----> Moving on.'
remote: -----> Moving on.
remote: ++ METEOR node -e 'process.stdout.write(process.execPath)'
remote: ++ ARGS='node -e process.stdout.write(process.execPath)'
remote: ++ HOME=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: ++ /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/meteor node -e 'process.stdout.write(process.execPath)'
remote: + METEOR_NODE=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node
remote: ++ dirname /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node
remote: + METEOR_NPM=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
remote: + '[' -z /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm ']'
remote: + '[' -z /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node ']'
remote: + NODE=/tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node
remote: + cp /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node
remote: + chmod a+x /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node
remote: ++ dirname /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
remote: + PATH=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin:/tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
remote: ++ /tmp/build_24f89da5/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node --version
remote: + echo '-----> Using node: v0.10.40'
remote: -----> Using node: v0.10.40
remote: ++ /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1dqp0mn.bwo9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm --version
remote: + echo '----->    and npm: 1.4.28'
remote: ----->    and npm: 1.4.28
remote: + '[' -e /tmp/build_24f89da5/package.json ']'
remote: + '[' -n '' ']'
remote: + echo '-----> Building Meteor app with ROOT_URL: https://staging.[redacted].com'
remote: -----> Building Meteor app with ROOT_URL: https://staging.[redacted].com
remote: ++ mktemp -d /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/build-XXXX
remote: + BUNDLE_DEST=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/build-PxVR
remote: + METEOR build --server https://staging.[redacted].com --directory /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/build-PxVR
remote: + ARGS='build --server https://staging.[redacted].com --directory /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/build-PxVR'
remote: + HOME=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor
remote: + /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/meteor build --server https://staging.[redacted].com --directory /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/6ec9c0780a117563073653c76abfcce030bc86ec/build-PxVR
remote: => Errors while initializing project:
remote: 
remote: While downloading accounts-base@1.2.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading accounts-password@1.1.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading alanning:roles@1.2.14...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading aldeed:collection2@2.8.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading aldeed:collection2-core@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading aldeed:schema-deny@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading aldeed:schema-index@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading aldeed:simple-schema@1.5.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading autoupdate@1.2.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading babel-compiler@5.8.24_1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading babel-runtime@0.1.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading base64@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading binary-heap@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading blaze@2.1.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading blaze-html-templates@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading blaze-tools@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading boilerplate-generator@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading browser-policy@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading browser-policy-common@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading browser-policy-content@1.0.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading browser-policy-framing@1.0.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading caching-compiler@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading caching-html-compiler@1.0.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading callback-hook@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:access-point@0.1.49...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:base-package@0.0.30...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:collection@0.5.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:collection-filters@0.2.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:data-man@0.0.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:ejson-file@0.1.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:file@0.1.17...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:filesystem@0.1.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:graphicsmagick@0.0.18...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:http-methods@0.0.30...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:http-publish@0.0.13...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:power-queue@0.9.11...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:standard-packages@0.5.9...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:storage-adapter@0.2.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:tempstore@0.1.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:upload-http@0.0.20...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading cfs:worker@0.1.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading check@1.1.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ddp@1.2.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ddp-client@1.2.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ddp-common@1.2.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ddp-server@1.2.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading deps@1.0.9...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading diff-sequence@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ecmascript@0.1.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ecmascript-runtime@0.2.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ejson@1.0.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading email@1.0.8...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading facts@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading fastclick@1.0.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading fortawesome:fontawesome@4.4.0_1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading geojson-utils@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading hot-code-push@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading html-tools@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading htmljs@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading http@1.1.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading id-map@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:controller@1.0.12...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:core@1.0.11...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:dynamic-template@1.0.12...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:layout@1.0.12...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:location@1.0.11...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:middleware-stack@1.0.11...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:router@1.0.12...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading iron:url@1.0.11...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading jparker:crypto-core@0.1.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading jparker:crypto-md5@0.1.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading jquery@1.11.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading kenken:meteor-counters@1.4.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading kenken:meteor-notifications@1.2.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading kenken:meteor-pagination@1.2.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading kenken:meteor-pubsub@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading kenken:meteor-utilities@2.10.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading launch-screen@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading livedata@1.0.15...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading localstorage@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading logging@1.0.8...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading mdg:validation-error@0.2.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading meteor@1.1.10...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading meteor-base@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading minifiers@1.1.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading minimongo@1.0.10...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading mobile-experience@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading mobile-status-bar@1.0.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading mongo@1.1.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading mongo-id@1.0.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading mongo-livedata@1.0.9...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading npm-mongo@1.4.39_1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading observe-sequence@1.0.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ordered-dict@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading percolate:synced-cron@1.3.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading promise@0.5.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading raix:eventemitter@0.1.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading raix:ui-dropped-event@0.0.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading random@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading rate-limit@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading reactive-dict@1.1.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading reactive-var@1.0.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading reload@1.1.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading retry@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading routepolicy@1.0.6...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading sergeyt:typeahead@0.11.1_7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading service-configuration@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading session@1.1.1...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading sha@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading spacebars@1.0.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading spacebars-compiler@1.0.7...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading srp@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading standard-minifiers@1.0.2...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading templating@1.1.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading templating-tools@1.0.0...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading tmeasday:publish-counts@0.7.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading tracker@1.0.9...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading ui@1.0.8...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading underscore@1.0.4...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading url@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading webapp@1.2.3...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote: While downloading webapp-hashing@1.0.5...:
remote: error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: cfb1747d388f7355ca13a4cdecc664a4c2e5b11e
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version cfb1747d388f7355ca13a4cdecc664a4c2e5b11e
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to [redacted].
remote:
```

###### Deployment target

Heroku

Comment: I think the `CERT_HAS_EXPIRED` is multiple times covered in the Meteor forums. Anything found there, that may help=